# The language field is not returned by the graph API call

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve the language field of a friend. It's not in the response when I make a call for basic profile info for a friend. I tried with the explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with all the permissions granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Languages" setting in the profile "Basic Information" tab corresponds to the Graph API `user` object `languages` field.

The "Languages" setting is optional and has a privacy setting; so you may get an empty result for a user if she hasn't set it, or if you're not allowed to see it.

Try the Graph API query `/me/friends?fields=languages` to see what's available for all your friends.  My results are like this:

```
...
{
  "id": "835399999"
},
{
  "languages": [
    { "id": "106059522759137", "name": "English" },
    { "id": "107672419256005", "name": "Dutch" }
  ]
  "id": "840799999"
},
...
```